# Problem regarding Wronskian

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations, wronskian

I have got a problem from Wronskian..I am a first reader of Differential Equation.

[image]

Can anyone please help me to solve this problem?

Attempt: I know that if $n$ number of $n-1$ differentiable function are dependent on $I$  then their Wronskian will be identically zero on $I$. But the converse of the theorem not true.

So by this theorem I can not do anything. If I had found a $x$ for which wronskian at the point $x$ is not zero ,  then we could have said the solutions are independent. But there is no such $x$.

Can anyone please correct me if I have misunderstood anywhere?

Comment: Indeed, for *arbitrary* differentiable functions $u_1, u_2$ you cannot deduce anything. But $u_1, u_2$ are solutions of a second order linear homogeneous ODE (with continuous coefficients), so it follows from the theory that the following conditions are equivalent: <ul> + $(u_1,u_2)$ are linearly independent; +$w(x)\ne0$ for all $x\in I$; + $w(x_0)\ne0$ for some $x_0\in I$.

Comment: So ONLY options 2 and 3 are correct?@user539887

Comment: Yes, they are correct: $w(0)=0$.

Answer (score 2):

Since $u_{1}$ and $u_{2}$ are two solutions of the given differential equation, so

$ \frac{d^2 u_1}{dx^2}+P(x)\frac{du_1}{dx}+Q(x)u_1 = 0$ . . . . . (1)

$ \frac{d^2 u_2}{dx^2}+P(x)\frac{du_2}{dx}+Q(x)u_2 = 0$ . . . . . (2)

Multiplying (2) by $u_1$ and (1) by $u_2$ and then subtracting we get,

$(u_2'' u_1 - u_1'' u_2)+P(x) (u_2' u_1 - u_1' u_2)+Q(x) (u_2 u_1 - u_1 u_2)=0$ where $u''=\frac{d^2 u}{dx^2}$ and $u'=\frac{du}{dx}$

$\implies \frac{dW}{dx}+P(x) W= 0$, where $W=\begin{vmatrix} u_1 & u_2 \\ u_1' & u_2' \end{vmatrix}$

$\implies W=ce^{-\int {P(x)} dx}$ , where $c$ is a constant of integration.  . . .  . .(3)

For $x=0$, $W=\begin{vmatrix} u_1(0) & u_2(0) \\ u_1'(0) & u_2'(0) \end{vmatrix}=\begin{vmatrix} 0 & 0 \\ u_1'(0) & u_2'(0) \end{vmatrix}=0$, since $u_1(0)=u_2(0)=0$(given)

Now $W=0$ for $x=0$ and hence from equation (3) we get, $c=0$

Therefore $W(x)=0$ remains same in the nbd. of $x=0$

Since Wronskian is zero, so $u_1(x), u_2(x)$ are linearly dependent. [**Option 2 is correct**]

Since $[-1,1]$ is a nbd. of $x=0$, so $W(x)=0$, for $x\in[-1,1]$. [**Option 3 is correct**]